# VueJS - change styles of pushed array element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this simple markup:

```
<div v-for="(node, index) in nodes" :key="index + 1">
   <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Along with this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nodes: [{
      left: 0,
      top: 0
    }],
  },
  addNode: function(position){
    this.nodes.push(position)
  }
})
```

Now, as soon as I call addNode(...) I would like the element to be inserted along with the styles I pass (in this case, controlling the positioning).

I tried doing it this way:

```
<div v-for="(node, index) in nodes" :key="index + 1" :style="{ 'left': note.left, 'right': note.right }">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

But that didn't seem to do much.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703527/apply-style-to-an-html-element-added-dynamically-by-v-for-using-vuejs

Comment: You have `notes` and `nodes` is that a typo?

Comment: oops, it was. But that's not the issue in the actual code.

Comment: Also, since your node is already and object containing some valid css properties, you can just do `:style="node"` as the style binding also accepts an object of css properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the unit after the value.

```
<div v-for="(node, index) in nodes" :key="index + 1" style="position:absolute" :style="{ 'left': note.left + 'px', 'right': note.right + 'px'}">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/140109/

Comment: Oh wow, when you don't see the elephant in the room... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used color as the style attribute to see the effects readily. But, its the same with the position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(node, index) in nodes" :style = "node">
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
   <button @click="addNode({color: 'blue'})">Add Node</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      nodes: [{
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      }],
    },
    methods:{
      addNode: function(position){
        this.nodes.push(position)
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps